# Ranorex create project run as administrator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ranorex

I need to create test suite that setup.exe can ran as administrator.  In visual studio we can do this by adding manifest file and then add following code.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I need to how can I do this in Ranorex studio. Can any one give me a useful link or solution. This is visual studio customize version can code using C#.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. 
Right click on your project solution then under properties select create in app manifest. then add following to your app.manifest file.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```